# MySQL select based on precedence of a column's values

Tags: mysql, sql

Say you have a dynamic view of a table that consists of the following entries

```
| id | type |
| 1  | cat  |
| 2  | dog  |
| 3  | bunny|
```

The catch with this is that sometimes there may not be an `id` with a `type` of `"cat"` it could potentially look like

```
| id | type |
| 1  | dog  |
| 2  | bunny|
```

How would one write a query for this table to select a single row based on precedence of `type`.

For example, if the ranking of `type` was `cat > dog > bunny`, I would want the first entry from that table with the highest ranking condition.

If we call our view `pets`, which has `ORDER BY id ASC` then we would have a query that looks something like this

```
SELECT *
FROM pets
WHERE type = 'cat' > 'dog' > 'bunny' -- here is where I need help
LIMIT 1
```

I've tried things like

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
       FROM   pets 
       WHERE  type = "cat") 

THEN SELECT * FROM pets WHERE condition = "cat" LIMIT 1
-- etc... down the ranking
```

Can't seem to get this to work though. Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, I would use `field()`:

```
SELECT *
FROM pets
WHERE type IN ('cat', 'dog', 'bunny')
ORDER BY field(type, 'cat', 'dog', 'bunny')
LIMIT 1
```

If you don't want to deal with the `WHERE` clause, you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM pets
ORDER BY field(type, 'bunny', 'dog', 'cat') DESC
LIMIT 1
```

You need to go backwards because non-matches are returned as `0`.

Comment: I like this as it is much more elegant than @D-Shih's proposal, I appreciate the feedback from you both. I'll try this when I get a moment, unfortunately have to step out right now and update which solution works best.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use `CASE WHEN` make the order number in `ORDER BY`, do your customer `order by` then `LIMIT 1`

```
CREATE TABLE pets(
  ID INT,
  type VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO pets VALUES ( 1  , 'cat');
INSERT INTO pets VALUES ( 2  , 'dog');
INSERT INTO pets VALUES ( 3  , 'bunny');
INSERT INTO pets VALUES ( 4 , 'TST');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM pets
ORDER BY CASE 
    WHEN type = 'cat' THEN 1  
    WHEN type = 'dog' THEN 2 
    WHEN type = 'bunny' THEN 3 
    ELSE 4  
    END 
LIMIT 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1d2118/3/0)**:

```
| ID | type |
|----|------|
|  1 |  cat |
```